# Excel spreadsheet into body of Gmail message without losing formatting

Tags: gmail, formatting, microsoft-excel

I am trying to copy and paste an Excel spreadsheet into the body of a Gmail message.  I know I can attach it but the recipient can't receive attachments.

The formatting stays but not the borders/lines and it's hard to read without borders/lines.  Why won't the borders transfer?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Apply "real" border lines.

## Explanation

The "default borderlines" in Excel and other spreadsheets application are named grid lines. They are a visual aid, not real formatting.